# Would plugins uses classes not supported by GAE cause runtime errors or be brought up at deployment

Tags: java, google-app-engine

If I use a library (jar) in my GAE app, and this library will have compiled dependency on class x that is not in the GAE's jre whitelist, would this be detected at local run, deployment, or I will have to find out about it through runtime exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your classes (present as Java source files in your source folders) reference classes not on the white-list, you will get notification (compile error) at compile time, and also when you try to deploy your app.

Jars however are not analyzed. You will only get notified about them run-time.